# reddit datasets in BigQuery - query the flairs?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, reddit

I know there's a dump of reddit comments and stories in BigQuery - as collected by Jason Baumgartner of pushshift.io.

How can I query this dataset to get a list of flairs for a subreddit?

This is the base query I have:

```sql
SELECT link_flair_text 
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2019_08` 
WHERE subreddit  = 'AmItheAsshole'
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's build this visualization:

[image]

- https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/1223278090958209025

A query like this will do - this one gets the count of posts on /r/AmITheAsshole, ordered by most typical judgement:

```sql
SELECT link_flair_text, COUNT(*) c 
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2019_08` 
WHERE subreddit  = 'AmItheAsshole'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]

To query several months of data, you can use `*` on the `FROM`:

```sql
SELECT link_flair_text, COUNT(*) c 
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2019_*` 
WHERE subreddit  = 'AmItheAsshole'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```

[image]

And to see the evolution of percentages per month:

```sql
SELECT link_flair_text, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(month, ROUND(100*c/total_month,1) AS perc, c) ORDER BY month) AS arr
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY month) total_month
  FROM (
    SELECT link_flair_text, DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc), MONTH)) month, COUNT(*) c
    FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2019_*` 
    WHERE subreddit  = 'AmItheAsshole'
    AND link_flair_text IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1,2 
    HAVING c > 100
  )
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY SUM(c) DESC
```

[image]

And the SQL for the viz shown above:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `temp.assholes`
AS
SELECT *, c/total_month AS perc
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY month) total_month, SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY link_flair_text) total_flair
  FROM (
    SELECT LOWER(link_flair_text) link_flair_text, DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc), MONTH)) month, COUNT(*) c
    FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.201*` 
    WHERE subreddit = 'AmItheAsshole'
    AND link_flair_text IS NOT NULL
    AND _table_suffix >= '8_03'
    GROUP BY 1,2 
  )
)
WHERE c/total_month > 0.01
AND total_flair > 1000
ORDER BY month
```

### How to bring data from before 2016?

Almost the same query, but it incorporates a different table that has all the historic content from before 2016:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.201*` WHERE _table_suffix >= '5_12'
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512`  
)

SELECT *, c/total_month AS perc
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY month) total_month, SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY link_flair_text) total_flair
  FROM (
    SELECT LOWER(link_flair_text) link_flair_text, DATE(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc), MONTH)) month, COUNT(*) c
    FROM data
    WHERE subreddit  = 'AmItheAsshole'
    AND link_flair_text IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1,2 
  )
)
WHERE c/total_month > 0.01
AND total_flair > 1000
ORDER BY month
```